# SVG Logo Animates but gets clipped by viewBox

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I successfully animated portions of an SVG logo but the outer edges end up outside of the viewBox when rotating. I've been playing with this for hours but can't figure out how to essentially add "padding" to the inside of the viewBox to give the animations room to complete.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="5px" y="5px" viewBox="0 0 625.1 160" style="enable-background:new 0 0 625.1 160;" xml:space="preserve" class="ccc-gear position-2">
    <g class="gear-group">
```

Here's a fiddle to demo exactly what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/inhouse/Labrz1vg/13/

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm certain to run into this with future projects as well!

Comment: An easy fix: `svg{overflow: visible;}` Alternatively you may need to change the `viewBox` attribute of your SVG

Comment: Dude, that's so easy! I was attempting solutions involving viewBox attributes but couldn't figure it out. Sometimes I wish I had other developers in the room to ask these questions! Add this as an answer and I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented: an easy fix to this problem is adding `svg{overflow: visible;}` in CSS.

However if this is not working you may want to tweak a little the code.

1. In your CSS you have `transform-origin: 13.2% 46.5%;`I've changed this to `transform-origin: 82.5px 74.5px;` since I want it hard coded. I'll change a little the size of the svg, and those percentages won't work any longer.  My numbers are a rough approximation. You may want to be sure this is what you need.
2. I've changed the `viewBox` to `-10 -15 625.1 180`. In your code you also have the `enable-background` with the same values as the `viewBox`. If you don't need it you may delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the CSS overflow answer (which works for me) and the additional info. I sincerely appreciate it. Cheers!